# Standard way to export code and data from aws ec2 to my local before stopping instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train a model using tensorflow object detection api on an AWS EC2 instance with p3.2xlarge GPU type. The ami I used during instance launch was a normal Ubuntu 20.04 (with no pre-installed packages).

Till now on this machine, I have:

1. Packages and drivers installed using `sudo apt-get`
2. Python virtualenvwrapper and python packages installed within it using `pip`
3. some repositories I cloned from github
4. some new files (`.ipynb`, `.txt`, `.zip`, `.jpg`, `.py`) that I created.

I have to stop the instance because it is costly. Is there a standard way to copy all the code and data as mentioned above into my local machine in a way that it could be used to recreate the environment in another (new) instance?

P.S.: I am aware of scp and downloading files using Jupyter, but looking for a more standard (and hopefully one-click kind of) approach.

Thanks.